# Spring MVC vs Java EE

Tags: spring

So I'm about to learn Spring MVC. But what I don't understand is why should I use Spring MVC if I can implement the MVC pattern using a single servlet conroller and JSPs? What advantages does Spring MVC provide over simple java MVC pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, you **can do it**. Question is if you should do it. Spring MVC gives you better organization of your code.

Pure MVC Frameworks like Spring MVC are obsolete today. When combined with templating engines like Thymeleaf, it lacks functionality and developers usually reinvent JSF. For single-page apps based on some popular JS frameworks that need REST backend, JAX-RS is way cleaner and better than Spring MVC REST.

So no, today **you don't need Spring MVC** and can stick with pure Java EE. For simple, toy-like applications where servlets are enough, you don't really need it but it **may be better to use it**. For anything serious, MVC is outdated and Spring has nothing to offer.

Edit 2017: Spring offers JAX-RS integration. However, it has several pitfalls, for example Spring won't automatically register classes annotated with @Path for you. Details can be found in [Dzone Article](https://dzone.com/articles/using-jax-rs-with-spring-boot-instead-of-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to realize that it's better to play with these technologies for yourself, if you want to try spring MVC I recommend you start with spring boot because you can create projects with more agility without configuring xml files

[Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)

Some Features

- Create stand-alone Spring applications
- Embed Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow directly (no need to deploy WAR files)
- Provide opinionated 'starter' POMs to simplify your Maven configuration
- Automatically configure Spring whenever possible
- Provide production-ready features such as metrics, health checks and 
  externalized configuration
- Absolutely no code generation and no requirement for XML configuration

Comment: This does not really answer his question, which is comparing Spring Boot with other patterns

Answer (score -3):

One of the ideas applied in Spring (not invented by Spring) is

> Do not reinvent a wheel.

Having a single controller is not a good idea I'd say - breaking separation of concerns principle.

You can learn more about MVC from [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-features).